# Paste valus from one excel sheet to anothes by matching names

Tags: excel, match, spreadsheet

I am having two tabs(Tab1 and tab2) , Tab 1 contains name(1100 rows) and roll numbers(1100 rows) of students while tab2 contains name(250 rows), now I want to match those 250 names from tab2 to tab1 and want to paste roll numbers of respective students in tab2

Answer (score 0):

In Tab 2, right next to student name, type this VLOOKUP formula:

=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)

where A2 is the first student name in your Tab2 list,
Sheet1 is your Tab1 (the 1100 list),
and 2 is the second column.

You can then drag this formula down to the rest of your Tab2 rows/records.